# How to select all elements based off of an attribute value containing a string in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, prototype

Here's my scenario.

I have the following inputs within a page.

```
<input name="myInput[field1]" value="field1value" type="text" />

<input name="myInput[field2]" value="field2value" type="text" />

<select name="myInput[select1]">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Using Prototype, I am trying to select all fields containing `myInput` within the `name` attribute and loop through each of them to append their values to a variable, like this:

```
var myVar = field1Value + field2Value + select1Value;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is the following:

```
var myVar;
$$('[name^="myInput"]').each( function(i) {
   myVar += i.value;        
});
```

They key to selecting all inputs, containing `myInput` in their `name` attribute is using the `^` symbol before the `=` sign.  So `[name^="myInput"]` is the correct selector to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
var myVar;
$$('input[name="myInput"]').each(function(i) {
    myVar += $(i).value; // Might be $(this).value
});
```

I don't write Prototype code much anymore but I *think* will work. If not, it should get you close enough to finish it off.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Are you sure that `input[name="myInput"]` encompasses `name="myInput[input1]"` also?

Comment: I *think* so. But if there's a bug it will be there. That selector may need to be tweaked to use the `~` selector: `input[name~="myInput"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a class to any fields that you want to sum up like so

```
var sum = 0;
$$('.addthese').each(function(i){
    sum += i.getValue()
});
```

This makes it more flexible as you don't have to worry about the names of the form elements as long as it has the class applied to it the value will be added

I used the `getValue()` method as it will smooth out problems with some form elements not having a `value` property in the DOM.